# Having difficulties stopping or exiting a method using a button in java

Tags: java, methods

I am developing a GUI program that searches for duplicates files. the problem i am currently facing is that when the search button is clicked it keep searching until it finishes. However, i want it in such a way that the user can cancel or stop it from searching by stopping the duplicate search method. I tried using the return statement inside the dupliate search method, but it is not working. Here is my code:

```
public void findDuplicateFiles(File[] files) throws IOException  {
    Map<String, List<File>> filesByHash = new HashMap<>();
    if(stop.getText() == "stop")
        return;

    for (File file : files) {
        if (!file.isFile()) {
            findDuplicateFiles(file.listFiles());
            continue;  
        }
        String hash = MD5.asHex(MD5.getHash(file));

        List<File> filesForHash = filesByHash.get(hash);
        if (filesForHash == null) { 
            filesByHash.put(hash, filesForHash = new ArrayList<>());
        }
        filesForHash.add(file);
    }
    for (Map.Entry<String, List<File>> entry : filesByHash.entrySet()) {
        List<File> filesForHash = entry.getValue();
        if (filesForHash.size() > 1) {
            String hash = entry.getKey();
            System.out.printf("%,d files have hash %s:%n", filesForHash.size(), hash);
            int index = filesForHash.size() - 1;
            filesForHash.remove(index);
            final DefaultListModel model = (DefaultListModel) list.getModel();

            for (final File file : filesForHash) {
                EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                    pathf.setText("Searching Files...." + file.getPath());
                        try {
                            System.getProperty("com.twmacinta.util.MD5.NO_NATIVE_LIB.MD5.dll");
                            MD5.initNativeLibrary();
                            model.addElement(file.getCanonicalFile());
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
                System.out.println("  " + file.getCanonicalPath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for your help..

Comment: You have to keep a reference on your new thread and kill it when the button is clicked or design the thread in a way that it is looping very often (once per file for example) and checks if a variable from the outer scope allows it to run further. The first way is safer but could lead to unclean shutdowns if not made properly.

Comment: @Johnride please can you give an example, do not really understand what you meant.

Comment: We need a little more detail before we can help.  First, you say "it is not working".  What do you mean exactly - it never stops, it doesn't stop quickly enough, or it throws an Exception?  Second - you call `stop.getText()` - we don't see what the stop variable is.  Is it a JButton? Is the text really changing when you click it?  Finally - think where the stop code is - it gets called only once per call to `findDuplicateFiles` Don't you want it within the inner loop (i.e. gets checked every time a file is checked)? If you give some more detail, we can probably help.

Comment: @J Richard Snape the " stop " variable is a JButton and it text is "Stop". whenever the stop button is clicked it never stop the method findDuplicateFiles method when looking for duplicate files. But after the findDuplicateFiles method finishes it process, when clicked again to search for a file it stops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, what happens is that you "plan" the processing of all files by adding a new thread to the call queue with `EventQueue.invokeLater`. As you coded it, you keep no reference on the runnables you create and, even if it is possible, it would not be a good idea to keep all of them and cancel them since you cannot really predict their state and all.

Then, as they are all planned they all run with no way to stop them since your main thread has no longer a direct reference on them.

The best way for you to solve your problem may look a bit complex but should also help you to better understand multi-threading : create a new class that implements Runnable but also provides a "stop" method (name it however you like). This new class would contain something like the code you posted but would not use invokeLater or anything like that, it would just execute the whole thing directly with an added check at the finest granularity possible.

Here is what it looks like :

```
public class DuplicateDetector implements Runnable{

private boolean canContinue = true;

public void run(){
    // prepare the file list and do the stuff you do not want to
    // run on the main thread
    this.startDetection();
}

private void startDetection(){
    for(File f : this.allYourFiles){

      // HERE IS THE KEY TO STOP YOU THREAD
      // Of course, this will only be checked once per file so
      // it will wait until the current file is finished before stopping
      // the execution
      if(this.canContinue){
         ...
      else{
        break;
      }
    }
    // detection finished, you can know if it ended naturally or because
    // of the cancel button with the value of this.canContinue
    // and provide the feedback you want
}

public synchronized void stop(){
  this.canContinue = false;
}

// Other possible functions to prepare the file list and stuff
}
```

And in the same thread that the UI is managed, you will keep a reference on the `Runnable` class so you can use it's stop function somewhere in the click event handler of your button.

I'm thinking of something like that (you could also use EventQueue.invokeLater) :

```
DuplicateDetector dupDet = new DuplicateDetector();
new Thread(dupDet).start();
```

And in the button's click handler you can use

```
dupDet.stop()
```

Safely since it is synchronized. Then the DuplicationDetector will stop gracefully the next time it checks the value of `canContinue` .

There are also dark ways to kill the thread but they pretty much all become deprecated one after the other. `interrupt` is the right way to do it but it will not allow your thread to provide feedback after the cancellation like how many files were processed, duplicates found etc.

A good way IMO would be to provide feedback during the execution, it is always good for the user. It can be as simple as a `getProgression` public method in the DuplicationDetector accessed periodically from the main thread, let your imagination go wild.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thanx so much for your help......It was really helpful, have been able to solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that when stop.getText() is "stop" you want to end the method.
First, '==' compares references, not objects, so it won't work, you'll have to use equals. Just in case, use it as "stop".equalsIgnoreCase(stop.getText()). That way is case-insensitive (maybe getText returns "Stop") and protected against null (in the case getText returns null)

Second, in the place it is, it will return if it's "stop" at the beginning of the checking on a folder, but it will keep going with the rest of the folder it was in.
To clarify, lets say you've got folder A, folder A/B and a lot of files under A. The method just entered the first for and stop.getText() changes to 'stop'.
In that for, you find folder B and make a second call that, since stop is already activated, returns immediately, but the first call will keep on with the rest of the files in folder A

Comment: i have tried your suggestion but still not working. when the findDuplicateFiles() method is clicked it just stops without searchingfor duplicate file. Please what should i do?